# How to put underline for access key for <asp:button>?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How to put underline for first letter for access key for  ?

Comment: Edited to remove your nick as a tag

Answer (score 4):

asp:buttons are output as html "input" tags with a type of "submit". The text displayed on them is output in the "value" attribute of the tag, and so cannot contain any styling or html. If you could get an asp:button to output as an html button then you could try something like:

```
<button id="mybutton" runat="server" onserverclick="myfunction">
<span style="text-decoration:underline;">P</span>rint</button>
```

and use a normal button event in your c# code:

```
protected void myfunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("clicked");
}
```

Comment: Just tested this in Visual Studio and it does the trick. I updated my post to change onclick to onserverclick.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the AccessKey attribute?

```
<asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Print" AccessKey="P" />
```

If it is really underlined is out of your control. The user agent (e.g. browser) is deciding that.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question. Given that he asked about an accesskey I'm betting he knows how to set that. I think he just wants to know how to make the button caption underline the character associated with the access key (it isn't automatic) so the user knows which one it is.

Comment: @JohnFX Have you read the *"If it is really underlined is out of your control."* part? Because that's the bottom line with an `<asp:button>`.